# Is it possible to have the E4 Application Model updated in an Eclipse project copy?

Tags: eclipse, e4

I want to create another copy of one of my Eclipse RCP projects.

In Project Explorer I can do a Copy and Paste and it will prompt me to rename the new copy but it seems like it does not update the Application Model with the new bundle name, so Handlers and Parts, for example, have Class URIs that still point to the original project.

Is there a way to get this updated, even possibly using a different copy technique?

Comment: I haven't seen anything. The e4xmi file is just XML so you should be able to edit it fairly easily.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer :-)

Comment: Yes, XMI, so a text file edit can be done but I was hoping the wizard would automate it. Apparently not. Thanks for the quick response, Greg, if you re-post it as an answer I will accept it as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to do this update.

The Application.e4xmi file is just an XML file so it could be edited fairly easily.